# Why does this Rust program ignore immutability

Tags: rust

I have the following Rust program and I expect it to result in an compilation error since `x` is reassigned later. But it complies and gives output. Why?

```
fn main() {
   let (x, y) = (1, 3);
   println!("X is {} and Y is {}", x, y);

   let x: i32 = 565;
   println!("Now X is {}", x);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rust actually lets you shadow other variables in a block, so `let x: i32 = 565;` is defining a *new* variable `x` that shadows the `x` defined earlier with `let (x,y) = (1,3);`. Note that you could even have redefined `x` to have a different type since the second `x` is a whole new variable!

```
fn main(){
   let x = 1;
   println!("Now X is {}",x);

   let x = "hi";
   println!("Now X is {}",x);
}
```

This [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2cho4g/why_does_rust_need_local_variable_shadowing/) goes into more detail about why this is useful. The two things that are mentioned that seem interesting are:

- For operations which take ownership of the variable, but return another variable of the same type, it sometimes "looks nice" to redefine the returned variable to have the same name. From [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-avoid-accidentally-redeclaring-a-variable-inside-a-code-block/8315/3):

  ```
  let iter = vec.into_iter();
  let iter = modify(iter);
  let iter = double(iter);
  ```
- Or to make a variable immutable:

  ```
  let mut x;
  // Code where `x` is mutable
  let x = x;
  // Code where `x` is immutable
  ```

Comment: Why this is allowed in language ? Doesn't this cause logic errors not easy to figure in large program ? What is the purpose of shadowing and is there any other language which uses these concept ?

Comment: How can you reference a previously-shadowed variable?

Comment: @Dai I don't think you can... You could always pass ownership to another variable `let y = x`.

Comment: @Viraj: It's allowed because it's found to be useful. Most languages allow shadowing to a degree, although Rust may be unique in that it allows shadowing in the same block. As for logic errors... it swing both ways. Sometimes being able to guarantee that the argument/variable is not accessed afterward is quite useful too. Honestly though I prefer not to use it.

Comment: I use shadowing for when I have an intermediary type, and I convert it into something else, knowing that I won't need it again. For example, a function has an argument  `foo: Option<u32>`, and I immediately unwrap it with `let foo = foo.unwrap_or(0)`. This saves me having to think of a new name for this variable, and prevents a future maintainer having to think about which similar-looking variable to use.