# immutability of rust let bindings

Tags: rust, immutability, let

I thought that  `let` is supposed to be an immutable binding.
Why does the correct code work then? (assigned `a` twice)

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
println! ("{:?}", a);

let (a, b, c) = (1,2,3);
println! ("{:?}", a);
println! ("{:?}", b);
println! ("{:?}", c);
```

And the result of cargo run is:

```
Guess the number! From a 1 - 100 inclusive
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1
2
3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this Rust program ignore immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991325/why-does-this-rust-program-ignore-immutability)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is more or less equivalent to this:

```
let first_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
println! ("{:?}", first_a);

let (second_a, b, c) = (1,2,3);
println! ("{:?}", second_a);
println! ("{:?}", b);
println! ("{:?}", c);
```

The second `a` is a completely new variable.  The first `a` is no longer accessible once you create a second one.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is being [shadowed](https://rustbyexample.com/variable_bindings/scope.html).

```
let a = 5;
a = 6; // not allowed

let a = 5;
let a = 6; //allowed
```

Bad form to do this in the same block like that.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's universally bad; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42991597/3650362) describes some possible uses. When the values aren't closely related, like in OP's example, that's confusing.